# Why is the product of the reaction "Bi + O2" Bi2O3 instead of Bi2O5?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, heat, ionic-compounds, periodic-table

I am stuck on a homework question that states:

> A piece of solid bismuth is heated strongly in oxygen.

The answer key states the answer as $\ce{Bi + O2 → Bi2O3}$. However, it is to my understanding that the metal Bismuth has a charge of +5 because of its location on the periodic table. Therefore, $\ce{(+5)[charge of Bi]*2 + (-2)[charge of oxygen]*5 = 0}$ giving me $\ce{Bi2O5}$. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many elements have multiple valencies. The most common oxidation state of Bi is +3. Bismuth (V) is also possible. Read more here on [Bismuth oxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth#Oxides_and_sulfides).

Answer (score 1):

It is true that bismuth burns with a bluish flame in the presence of air to form bismuth trioxide($\ce{Bi2O3}$) as @M.Farooq mentioned. [Bismuth pentoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth_pentoxide) is not a pure compound but a mixture of various compounds like water, bismuth trioxide and bismuth tetroxide. It is also not stable at strong heat, decomposing at 393 K. [Also, there is no direct preparation for this compound.](http://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-bismuth-pentoxide/) You have to first make bismuth trioxide and then react with a bunch of other chemicals to form bismuth pentoxide.

So, the balanced reaction would be:

$$\ce{4Bi + 3O2 ->[\Delta] 2Bi2O3}$$